# Node.js uv_async_send

Tags: node.js, libuv

I am compiling a visually designed process model (A series of connected boxes) to run on the Node event loop. I have an instance of a class which uses uv_async_send to "Post" an event, with a callback pointing to another instance of the class. The seconds instance then "calls back" repeatedly the first class to get more data, using the same mechanism.

With nothing else running, I'm seeing a round trip of 30 to 40 microseconds.

It's slow, or at least slower than I hoped for. I am using sending the callback events to the default loop.

Does anyone know how I might speed this up a bit? 30 microseconds is a lot of instructions...

I know most of you would probably like to see code, but it's late now, so maybe tomorrow. I was just hoping it might ring a bell with someone.

Comment: Curious why you think 30us is slow? That's 33,000 "posts" per second.

Comment: The client wants to be able to pass 250,000 messages per second between boxes. I have built a standalone C++ supervisor that easily does this, but  was trying to make it a "good citizen" on Node, so that it uses the callback model, thus not blocking the main event loop for a long time. For example when a starting Box reads a file containing 2 Million lines, and it pumps those out to another box, I wanted it to be event-driven.